# Finding the ID of a group of elements SQL or Math issue

Tags: sql, math

Good day all,

I am presented with an issue.

I have 2 tables of objects.

TABLE A has 3 rows
A, B, C
with IDs of
1, 2, 3

TABLE B has lets say 10 rows
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J
with IDs of
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

TABLE B has a FK linking to Table A based on the ID column
lets say starting from top to bottom 1-10 we have the FK column with the following values:
1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,2

Above you can see we have 5 entries of 1, 3 entries of 2, and 2 entries of 3.

My issue:

I want to come up with a method that I can have new IDs for each group.
1,2,3,4,5 for the TABLE A entry A
1,2,3 for the TABLE A Column B
1,2 for the Table A Column C

Basically I want the ID Count of based on the ID of TABLE B.  So if this is the First time the FK is up, i want the new ID to 1, if it is the 2nd i want it to be 2. and so on.

Below is an example of what I mean

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Car</th><th> </th><th>Person</th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>CarTypeID</td><td>NEWID</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>TypeA</td><td>1</td><td>Waylon</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>TypeB</td><td>2</td><td>Justine</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>TypeC</td><td>3</td><td>Abdullah</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>4</td><td>Marcus</td><td>1</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>5</td><td>Thalia</td><td>1</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>6</td><td>Mathias</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>7</td><td>Eddie</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>8</td><td>Angela</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>9</td><td>Siena</td><td>1</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td>10</td><td>Joe</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) window function like this:

```
select 
   id, 
   name, 
   row_number() over (partition by CarTypeID order by id) as [newid]
from Person
order by id
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, this did exactly what I wanted